# How to save text in Uitextview for iphone

Tags: uitextview

Notes as a UITextView  in navigation base application .How to save text data after writing in notes .How to identify return from keyboard. need to set any key for return Notes.I need to store device. When user enter the text in notes , after second time able  to see previous page also, if its possible write to previous page end of line to start that is appended.  plz post some tutorial link , because i am not much  about this topic, i need ti understand concept .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create function that is called on a button click, test if the user has hit enter, or test if the user has removed focus from the UITextView:

```
-(IBAction)saveText
{
```

Get the path to the file you want to create:

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentTXTPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"savedText.txt"];
```

Get the text from the UITextView (replace textView with the name of your UITextView):

```
NSString *savedString = textView.text;
```

Write the string to the file:

```
    [savedString writeToFile:documentTXTPath atomically:YES];
}
```

Comment: Edited question . why need to create button , Because user enter in Notes , want to write , and check with keyboard with back/close to writing text, once writing is finished i need to save with automatically. where is this button click.

Comment: You could also use the delegate methods on UITextField: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

Comment: @joshpaul thanks, that's what I was originally thinking of explaining at the top but I totally blanked xD