# Save data in UITextView to file?

Tags: objective-c

I'm working with an SSH library and I have a part in my application where you can create an HTML document by writing it in UITextView, then I want to be able to upload it to the server. I'm stuck on the part where I have to save the text file in a ".html" format temporarily, before uploading to a server. I know I can get all the text from the text view, but how do I give it a filename extension? 
Thanks!

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530422/how-to-save-text-in-uitextview-for-iphone) SO thread to learn about saving it to file, but how do I access the file once it's saved?

```
NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *documentTXTPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.html"];


htmlCode = self.htmlText.text;
NSError* error = nil;
[htmlCode writeToFile:documentHTMLPath atomically:YES encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
NSStringEncoding encoding;
NSString* fileToUpload = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:documentHTMLPath usedEncoding:&encoding error:&error];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the URL of the file you are writing to, than you use that same URL to access the file again.

**edited to add**

```
NSURL *documentDirectoryURL = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];

NSURL *documentURL = [documentDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.html"];


htmlCode = self.htmlText.text;

NSError* error;

if (![htmlCode writeToURL:documentURL atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't save file because: %@", error);
}

NSString* fileToUpload = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:documentURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

if (!fileToUpload) {
    NSLog(@"Couldn't read file because: %@", error);
}
```

- It's preferable to use URLs rather than string paths nowadays.
- Use UTF8 wherever you can
- **Always** use the NSError parameter when it is available to you. Even the rudimentary error handling that I've shown here is better than none at all when you are wondering why you can't save or read files.
- And yes, the URL you save to is the same URL you read from. In this case it is `documentURL`

Comment: Thanks! If I used what I've added in my above code, what string would the path be? documentTEXTPath?